# How to use MapView in Android Studio 3.3 canary 13?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mapview

I am using `Android Studio 3.3 canary 13`. The app is crashing with this message.

I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #274: Binary XML file line #274: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #274: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file .
```

Can anyone help on how to use `MapView` in `AndroiX`?

Problematic XML line:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_address"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    />
```

Comment: Have you added google map service dependency or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this work, just define in your `AndroidManifast.xml`

Add First:-

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyC6TVk6gtR_i_.......**************"/>
```

Then:-

```
<meta-data 
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="@integer/your_google_maps_version" />
```